# delete MongoDb document based on another deleted document that contains item id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-populate, mongoose-schema

I have a mongoDb Schema

```
var eventSchema = new Schema({
    title :{type: String, required: true},
    description : String,
    adress : String,
    country :String,
    createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    createEnd: {type: Date},
    state : Boolean,
    userid: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'Organizer'}
});
```

and another `appelOffre` Schema that contain and id from the previews schema

```
var appelOffreSchema = new Schema({
    title: {type: String, required: true},
    description : String,
    category : {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'Category'},
    retraitCahierCharge : String,
    createdOn: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    createEnd: {type: Date},
    state : Boolean,
    userid: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'Organizer'},
    eventid: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId , ref: 'Event'}
});
```

I want to automatically delete the 2nd when the first is deleted. Any help?

Comment: can you provide a link of the other question ?

Comment: There is a link. Right at the top of the question.